# trouble installing jdee and cedet in emacs

Tags: file, emacs, directory, cedet, jdee

I'm not sure what's going wrong here and I'm failry new to emacs in general... I started with trying to install JDEE (downloaded it, extracted into directory below) into emacs with this code

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/internet/jdee-2.4.1/lisp")
(load "jde")
```

in my.emacs file and I was getting the error "Cannot find wget. You might want to use the beanshell resolver instead." upon M-x eval-buffer

I'm not sure what's going on there since I have wget with xcode on my mac. But I looked up about jdee and i found that i might want cedet. So I download that, put it into .emacs.d and even add

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/Users/paulmyers/.emacs.d/internet/cedet-1.1/cedet-build.el")
```

to my .emacs but whenever I run

```
emacs -Q -l cedet-build.el -f cedet-build
```

from my terminal like it tells me to, I get the message

```
"Cannot open load file: no such directory, cedet-build.el"
```

I don't know what to do at this point...

Comment: What version of Emacs do you have? (Check with `M-x version`.) You likely already have CEDET installed since it has been bundled with Emacs since version 24.2. You can also run `M-x cedet-version` to see which version of CEDET and related tools you have.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure CEDET works well before trying jdee. 
Get the last CEDET http://sourceforge.net/p/cedet/git/ci/master/tree/ and the last jdee http://sourceforge.net/p/cedet/git/ci/master/tree/ .

Here my cedet conf (at the beginning of your .emacs):

```
 (ignore-errors ;; for cedet reload
    (load-file "~/.emacs.d/cedet-git-master/cedet-devel-load.elc")
    (load-file "~/.emacs.d/cedet-git-master/cedet-contrib-load.elc"))
  (global-ede-mode 1)
  (add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semanticdb-minor-mode 1)
  (add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-idle-scheduler-mode 1)
  (add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-stickyfunc-mode 1)
  (add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-highlight-func-mode 1)
  (add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-idle-summary-mode t)
  (add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-idle-completions-mode t)
  (add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-srecode-minor-mode t)
  (semantic-mode)
```

And my jdee conf

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/jdee/jdee-master") 
(autoload 'jdee-mode "jdee" "" t)   
(setq auto-mode-alist (append '(("\\.java\\'" . jdee-mode)) auto-mode-alist))  
 (setq jde-complete-add-space-after-method t)  
 (setq jdee-server-dir "~/.emacs.d/jdee/jdee-server-master/target/")  
 (add-hook 'jdee-mode-hook 
            (lambda()
              ;; abbrev
              ;;(jdee-abbrev-mode)
              ;; autocomplete
              (add-to-list 'ac-modes 'jdee-mode)))
```

Then use M-x custumize-group jdee for JAVA variables (JAVA_HOME, CLASSPATH...)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding JDEE, in your place I would install in from MELPA using emacs package manager. This is the recommended way to install it.